# Why ground set of submodular function maximization is finite set?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, matroids

There is famous statement for submodular function maximization by greedy algorithm, roughtly:

> greedy submodular maximization algorithm is guaranteed to be
> $(1-\frac{1}{e})$-optimal approximate algorithm.

Original paper (Nemhauser 1978) and other overview article (e.g. Kraus 2014) state the above statement for submodular set function $f: 2^V \to \mathbb{R}$ where ground set $V$ is finite set.

My question is on finiteness of $V$. Reading through the proof of the above statement (e.g. page 7 of Kraus 2014), the statement can also hold when $V$ is infinite.

Comment: @aroyc thanks! Could you list some of the active researches related to the infinite case?

Comment: I had to delete the comment as I ran out of the limit. Rather I've added as answer. I'm sorry, for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations! You've hit the nail on the head. Generally, people define a problem in a way that is not too obvious, but the approach they present carries a sense of "progress" towards solving the problem.

To be honest, there is no harm in defining the problem of maximization such that V can be infinite, and it's still an active area of research. In my humble opinion, the main difficulty arises when $|V| = \infty$, as not all elements might be enumerable within a finite time. Under this scenario, it's not obvious how to efficiently search in general. Of course, one can come up with an interesting scenario (e.g., assuming some particular structure of the set $V$ or a special class of submodular function that might offer an "interesting" setting). However, finding such a kind of $V$ and class of submodular functions and establishing its relevance for which it should be regarded as "interesting" is a research problem in its own right.